# Inspect CSS from Content Script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a content script and I know my CSS is being injected. It works. But I can't see the styles in the inspector. I'm using Chrome 21.0.1180.89 on a Mac.

Is there some ttrick to see the content script styles in the inspector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see injected CSS in "Computed Style" section of inspector.